# how to use data of AnonymousType separately?

Tags: asp.net, arrays, sql-server, entity-framework, multidimensional-array

i am creating a program with asp.net and using entity framework  for sql server

```
MyEntitiesCONF db = new MyEntitiesCONF();
           var query = (from p in db.f
                         join q in db.members
                         on p.friend_id equals q.ID
                         where p.uid == 1
                         select new
                         {
                             name = q.Name,
                             id = p.friend_id,

                         }).ToArray();
```

when i execute the query, i will get a {<>f__AnonymousType1[6]}
which means  it is an anonymous type  with 6 returns( each one have 2 field name and id )
so it is something like an 2d array
this is my question, how i can use this 2d data?
i want dynamically use each 6 ID field somewhere and name fields in other places,
any idea?
and another question, how can i get a array list, not an anonymous type
thanks

Comment: Use tuples, for example.

Comment: would you explain more? how, can you write the code