# How connect 2 SQL Server tables with a query and use data dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have two table in SQL Server; one is `member` table and the other is `friend` table.

- In `member` table, we have information of members, like username password etc
- In `friend` table, we have `userID` and `FriendID`, so we can know each user how many friend have

So with Entity Framework in ASP.NET:

- how can I write a query to get friends names and ID of one member?

[Tables look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7h57.png)

[An example of friend table, you can see user with `ID = 1` has a few friend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG5s2.png)

Comment: Use `JOIN` statement for connect 2 tables... Basically [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: @behzad, see updated answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try joining like this:

```
select * from member a join friend b on a.id=b.userid
```

Comment: i used join, but have this problem [see this link ! for my new problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530395/how-to-use-data-of-anonymoustype-separately)

Comment: Just describe the problem please

Comment: i used join with entity framework, then in my var query    i have f__AnonymousType1 type,  and i cant use data from it.i want to use ID seperatly and use   name in somewhere else, so i need seprate them  and use it with for to fill data

Comment: can you create a view and then call that?

Comment: edited last comment (up).            you mean  i create a view in sql server?

Comment: i guess i can ,  but view use less resource and speed or  using join?

Comment: a view is just a saved predefined query thats all - your join will be in the view

Comment: its just a saved query thats all- when the data changes the results of the view will change

Comment: ok thanks for help daniel, if you can help me to use data from join query i would be appreciate.    [my problem with join query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530395/how-to-use-data-of-anonymoustype-separately)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for you.

You have to do join and you can do it in SQL query.
Or you can make LINQ join

Either way you will need to use JOIN

Comment: i used join, but have this problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530395/how-to-use-data-of-anonymoustype-separately)